# BlockingQueueConnection and QueueConnection

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Делаю одновременный запрос нескольким экземплярам оборудования через `std::thread` (не спрашивайте, почему не через `QThread`). Ответы на запрос упаковываю в структуры и возвращаю через сигнал, который вызывает слот, отображающий данные на графическом интерфейсе. Собственно, когда использую `Qt::QueuedConnection`, через раз происходит так, что слот выполняется только один раз, для потока, подавшего сигнал первым. Если использовать `Qt::BlockedQueuedConnection`, то всё выполняется как нужно. Почему так?
Как примерно это выглядит,

cтруктура:

```
struct DataFromThread
{
    int serial_number;
    QVector <std::tuple<double,double,double,int>> measure_vector;
    GMS mean_Hz;
    GMS mean_V;
    GMS sko_Hz;
    GMS sko_V;
};
```

Cигнал:

```
signals:
    void readyDataFromThread(DataFromThread data);
```

Connect:

```
connect(this,&MainWindow::readyDataFromThread,this,&MainWindow::data_from_thread_handler,Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

Функция, выполняющаяся в нескольких потоках:

```
void MainWindow::parallel_makeMeasure()
{
    //до этого момента запрашиваю данные
    DataFromThread data;
    data.serial_number=serial_number;
    data.mean_Hz=EV_hz_angle;
    data.mean_V=EV_v_angle;
    data.sko_Hz=sko_hz_angle;
    data.sko_V=sko_v_angle;
    data.measure_vector=measure_vector;
    emit readyDataFromThread(data);
    //после отправки выполняю ещё какие-то операции
```

Вызов функции в потоке:

```
std::thread thd1(&MainWindow::parallel_makeMeasure,this);
thd1.detach();
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это чудо, что работает. Т.к. в потоке std::thread нет цикла обработки сообщений Qt. Возможно сообщение не доходит, т.к. поток убивается раньше чем сообщение будет доставлено.

Comment: @Unick, ну, не знаю... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982324/qt-emit-a-signal-from-a-c-thread

Comment: Исходя из написаного, могу сказать, что при обработке очереди, очередь (или указатель на елемент очереди) - хранится в памяти. Если им управлять без блокировки, то два thread-а могут "потерять" елемент очереди, что б этого не было, при **одновременном** доступе к голове или хвосту очереди нужно делать блокировку иначе после изменения будет принята правка одного из thread а вторая правка утеряна, а в BlockedQueueCollection это уже учтено. Под правкой я имею ввиду добавление/извлечение из очереди.

Comment: @nick_n_a, интересно, впервые слышу об этом. как можно обратиться к очереди событий в qt?

Comment: Queue - переводится как очередь.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я не о том. я вас понял, вы говорите, что нужно блокировать очередь событий на момент отправки сигнала. так вот, как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем, если BlockedQueueConnection это учтено? Но если нужно QueueConnection почитайте "mutex c++" или "critical sections c++". Почитать о разрешение конфликтов многозадачности. Грубо говоря, нужно создать mutex, и на время добавления или чтения очереди блокировать его, а потом отпускать. На msdn описание https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @nick_n_a, я знаю про мьютексы и всё остальное, я, наверное, неправильно задаю вопрос. в случае, если мы используем неблокированную очередь действительно возможен одновременный доступ и потеря элемента очереди. но мне не понятно, как это решается в случае blockingqueue, ведь она, судя по описанию, блокирует поток, пока не выполнится вызванный слот, а не саму очередь событий, посему и в этом случае, возможен одновременный emit сигнала. или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что в справке написано об идентичности блокирующего и неблокирующего вызовов слота через сигнал (кроме, собственно, блокировки потока-источника), отличия они имеют.

Если посмотреть исходники Qt, то в файле `qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp`, в методе `QMetaObject::activate()` содержится ответ, почему поведение всё же различается. Для соединений типа `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` отправка события на вызов слота в поток-цель производится сразу и без всяких проверок на регистрацию метатипов передаваемых аргументов, тогда как для `Qt::QueuedConnection` предварительно вызывается статическая функция `queued_activate()`, которая в обязательном порядке производит обозначенную проверку.

Если структура `DataFromThread` не зарегистрирована через `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` и `qRegisterMetaType()`, то вполне вероятно именно это является причиной возникающих проблем при вызове слотов через очередь.

Comment: структура зарегистрирована, так что проблема, видимо, не в этом. а одновременный emit в потоках не может быть причиной тому, что один вызов теряется?

Comment: Вряд ли, всё равно всё сводится к `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`, а этому методу, по идее, без разницы должно быть. Но можете проверить, например, каким-нибудь статичным мьютексом.

Comment: хотя, вы, вероятно, правы. я делал qRegisterMetaType (потому что мне как раз выдало предупреждение на этот счёт при попытке connect-а), но не сделал прежде Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, хотя в документации сказано "Call this function to register the type T. T must be declared with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(). Returns the meta type Id.". Но, в таком случае всё равно странно, почему это приводит к неким "перебоям", а не возвращению пустой структуры во всех случаях, и некоторые потоки возвращают структуру, а остальные нет. В общем, завтра проверю и отмечу ответ как правильный, если поможет.

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что при неблокирующем вызове некоторые потоки не успевают завершиться прежде, чем вызовется слот, и информация о структуре, её типе остаётся доступна. Блокирующий вызов вполне определённо намекает именно на это.

Comment: не очень вас понял, я вызвал emit signal() и он отправил сигнал со структурой в главный поток, где тот встал в очередь на обработку, причем здесь то, что поток не успевает завершиться, если данные уже отправлены?

Comment: Если данные не зарегистрированы, то то, что окажется в очереди, большой вопрос, поскольку иначе и не нужна была бы никакая предварительная регистрация через `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`. Но если поток-источник ещё жив, то хранит и информацию о структуре, которая передаётся через сигнал.

Comment: всё, я вас понял. спасибо за объяснение